# Yii 2 Acceder al controller desde un boton?

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Este es mi controlador:

```
public function start()
{
    var_dump('hola');exit;
}
```

Este es mi boton:

```
<?= Html::a('<i class="material-icons md-84">play_arrow</i>', ['class' => 'submit-button']) ?>
```

¿Hay alguna forma de acceder a la función start() desde mi botón?

Comment: Podrias acceder como si fuese una action. @David

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo? @danit

Answer (score 0):

En Yii2 para acceder desde fuera a metodos del controlador , este metodo se tiene que llamar actionXXX. 
[Documentacion oficial](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/es/structure-controllers)

```
public function actionStart() {
         return "hola";
}
```

Y ya realizas la llamada haciendo

```
<?= Html::a("Prueba", ['controller/start'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

el boton debe tener la palabra action al principio para poder acceder a la funcion mediante url, ejemplo:

```
public function actionStart(){
    var_dump('hola');exit;
}
```

y en la vista lo puede llamar asi

```
<?= Html::a("Prueba", ['controller/start'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```